# Long running jobs in emacs org mode

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

When I execute a long running script within the org mode, emacs freezes. Is there a way to see the (running) output of the script? Alternatively, is there a way to run script asynchronously, and then get the output back into the org buffer?

I run my shell scripts the following way:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell
 ls
#+END_SRC
```

Thank you!

Edit: May be there is a way to run the command in a separate buffer, to observe output, and the put truncated output back to the main buffer?

Comment: Can you give us a minimal working example of how you run your script using `org-mode`?

Comment: @lawlist I added a code example

Comment: Thank you.  I was able to get the minimal working example to work by first evaluating `(require 'ob-shell)`.

Comment: I did some preliminary tracing using the minimal working example and found that it uses the function `process-file`, which calls `call-process` -- both of which have an optional argument for DISPLAY, with limitation notations in the doc-strings; e.g., "*Some file handlers might not support all variants, for example they might behave as if DISPLAY was nil, regardless of the actual value passed.*"  I tried using the DISPLAY argument, but that did not appear to achieve your desired affect.  You may wish to explore working on a custom solution that utilizes `start-process` instead ...

Comment: @lawlist Can you please put notes from your exploration as an answer, so I can reproduce it? Thank you.

Comment: I would prefer to leave the question without an answer for the time being to encourage other forum participants to spin their wheels searching for an approach that may suit your needs.  **Step 1**:  Open a recent version of Emacs such as 26.1 to 26.3.  **Step 2**:  Evaluate `(require 'ob-shell)` with something like `M-:` aka `M-x eval-expression`.  **Step 3**:  Type `M-x find-function RET org-babel--shell-command-on-region RET`.  **Step 4**:  Copy the entire function and paste it into a scratch buffer; and, underneath the line `(delete-region start end)`, type `(message "hello-world")` ....

Comment: **Step 5**:  Evaluate the modified function with something like `M-x eval-buffer`.  **Step 6**:  Open a new scratch buffer and paste your minimal working example, and type `M-x org-mode`.  **Step 7**:  Place your cursor on the first line of the source code block and type `C-c C-c` and then enter "yes" when prompted.  **Step 8**:  Switch to the `*Messages*` buffer and observe the line that contains the printed message "*hello-world*".  Because the message was generated immediately prior to the line `(setq exit-status (process-file ...)`, we know that the function `process-file` gets invoked.

Comment: **Step 9**:  Type `M-x find-function RET process-file RET` and review the code, which calls the function `call-process`.  **Step 10**:  Review the doc-strings for both `process-file` and `call-process`.  **Step 11**:  Feel free to try and see if using the optional DISPLAY argument for each function (e.g., by setting it to `t`) has any desired/noticeable affect, which resulted in no observable changes for me on OSX 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard).  **Step 12**:  Google up some examples where `start-process` is used with `set-process-sentinel` for some ideas on how to proceed.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed steps!

Answer (score 1):

> Alternatively, is there a way to run script asynchronously, and then get the output back into the org buffer?

There is a great package for that: [ob-async](https://github.com/astahlman/ob-async)

Just add `:async` to your header (or in a drawer, etc.).

Unfortunately I don't know of any way to monitor the process as it runs, though.